# Applying an opacity (or Paint) when drawing a Picture onto a Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

As one of the authors of [Sharp](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp) (scalable vector graphics for Android), I'm trying to find an effective way to apply group opacity.

Suppose we have the following SVG:

[image: Group transparency example]
Source SVG: [group_transparency.svg](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp/blob/b9c17fbdb79298005db25b044a4f0320cc931873/sample-imageview/src/main/res/drawable/group_transparency.svg)

Simplified snippet from the SVG:

```
<svg ...>
  <g ...>
    <path ...
       style="stroke:#ffcc00;stroke-width:20;" />
    <circle ...
       style="fill:#00cc00;opacity:0.5;" />
    <circle ...
       style="fill:#cc0000;opacity:0.5;" />
    <g ...
       style="opacity:0.5">
      <circle ...
         style="fill:#00cc00;" />
      <circle ...
         style="fill:#cc0000;" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Note the differences between the two pairs of circles: the top pair each have half opacity, which results in the red and green blending. The bottom pair have full opacity, but the group containing them is ultimately drawn at half opacity, and hence there is no blending of green and red.

My first approach was to keep track of a stack of Pictures, drawing them when the group end tag was encountered:

```
SvgGroup g = mGroupStack.pop();
mCanvas = g.canvas;
Picture p = g.picture;
p.endRecording();
mCanvas.drawPicture(p);
```

SvgGroup is a simple class:

```
private class SvgGroup {

    private Picture picture;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private float opacity;

}
```

The immediate problem here is that I cannot apply the opacity when drawing the Picture onto the Canvas as I cannot provide a Paint as a parameter of `Canvas.drawPicture()`.

The only way I've found to draw the group with correct opacity, is by drawing the Picture first into a Bitmap:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(p.getWidth(), p.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
p.draw(c);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha((int) (255 * g.opacity));
mCanvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, paint);
```

While this works, the benefits of using Picture are lost as it is rasterized. Zooming in illustrates the problem with each approach (left: drawing a Picture; right: drawing a Bitmap):

[image]
[image]

Clearly—from the name of this project—this is not what I want! Is there any way to retain the obvious benefits of using a Picture, while being able to apply an opacity to it as a whole?

Comment: i am not sure if i get you right but maybe `Canvas#saveLayer` is your friend?

Comment: @pskink I had completely overlooked that possibility, thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into it.

Comment: or even better in your case `saveLayerAlpha` ;-)

Comment: Brilliant, that worked perfectly! Feel free to add it as an answer, and I'll edit it with my one-liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I would use: [`Canvas#saveLayer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#saveLayer(android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint)) or [`Canvas#saveLayerAlpha()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#saveLayerAlpha(android.graphics.RectF,%20int,%20int)).

With the former you could use the Paint parameter with `setAlpha()` (but I'm not 100% sure if it works), with the latter it should be easier and safer to use:

> The alpha parameter is applied when the offscreen bitmap is drawn back when restore() is called.

Comment: Indeed it was trivial to get working. When entering the group, I call: `mCanvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, mCanvas.getWidth(), mCanvas.getHeight(), (int) (255 * opacity), Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG)`, and when leaving it, simply `mCanvas.restore()`.